# Postgrest query. Select * from table when id = id or (user id = id and boolean = true)

Tags: postgresql, postgrest

Im trying to do what a simple query in postgres on postgrest.

Basically this is the query I am trying to recreate
(ID, Other_id and boolean are all columns in the table)

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ID = 'ID' 
   OR (OTHER_ID = 'OTHER_ID' AND BOOLEAN = true);
```

I have tried the postgrest url below (following the docs)

**https://table?and=(id.eq.id,or(boolean.is.true,other_id.eq.other_id))
but it isn't working.**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what does "not working" mean ?

Comment: Returns the incorrect data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you need to pass it like this :

```
https://table?or=(id.eq.id,and=(boolean.is.true,other_id.eq.other_id))
```

based on documentations , the syntax is like opertaor=(operand1 , operand2)
, so basically you are doing "or" first because this is what you are doing

OR=(x,Y) but then Y is a mixed criteria so OR=(x,AND=(a,b))

hopefully that clears up.

Comment: Perfect, can you explain why the or is first?